# Combine independent form with DetailView

Tags: python, django, detailview

I want to display DetailView and independent form to send API request to the other website server. I made views.py but only i get is empty page. I'm trying to figure out how to adjust it for over past fiew days and still don't have any clue how to do this. Hope you will help me with this

**views.py**

```
class DetailPostDisplay(DetailView):
    model = EveryPost
    template_name = 'post/detailpost.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = DictForm()
        return context

class DictWindowForm(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'post/detailpost.html'
    form_class = DictForm
    model = EveryPost

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('detailpost', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})

class DetailPostList(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = DetailPostDisplay.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = DictWindowForm.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**HTML**
I'm not sure whether action should be empty or include url **DetailPostDisplay**(require to pass slug, which i don't have how to get)

```
        <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark float-right mt-2" value="Tłumacz">
        </form>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import PostListPl, PostListRu, DetailPostDisplay

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListPl.as_view(), name='index_pl'),
    path('ru/', PostListRu.as_view(), name='index_ru'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', DetailPostDisplay.as_view(), name='detailpost'),
]
```

Comment: It's not clear which url you enter in your browser bar that's not working and what you mean by "I get empty page". Which page? I think you're trying to add a form to your detailed view, then your `DictWindowForm` view is correct (just why is called Form if it's a View) and you should use that **instead** of the `DetailPostDisplay` (you can remove it entirely).

Comment: Also `{{ object }}` is the specific `EveryPost` in your template so probably `{{ object.slug }}` is the slug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the future generations, i mixed and overthinked it. If you want to just put form into DetailView, create def post and put logic there. Code below:

**views.py**

```
class DetailPostDisplay(DetailView):
    model = EveryPost
    template_name = 'post/detailpost.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailPostDisplay, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = DictForm
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = DictForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            self.object = self.get_object()
```

And later code to pass variables into template from form

```
            context = super(DetailPostDisplay, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['form'] = DictForm
            context['word'] = request.POST.get('word')
            return self.render_to_response(context=context)
```